# How do I setup an off-server email system, similar to Google apps.. but not Google...?

Tags: email, imap, cname-record, mx-record

We have a website hosted on a server that does not have any type of mail system installed.

I want to setup an IMAP and POP email system for my company.  We want ournames@ourdomain.com (in otherwords, not ournames@hotmail.com) - and I know you can setup Google Apps and host email through them, and just setup MX records, but we do not want to use Google.  I also know you can use MS Exchange... but again - not really interested in paying if we can avoid it.

So I was wondering....

If our primary server does not have mail installed... but we also have a cpanel account with a separate host.... is it somehow possible to host our website on the server it's on now, but somehow connect the email to the cpanel account we have with another provider - either by changing MX records... CNAME records, or A records......?  Do we need a dedicated IP address with the cpanel account....?  How would we configure something like that?

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question. Try asking it on ServerFault.

Other than that, please specify - are you interested in a Webmail solution, like GMail, or IMAP\POP server without a web frontend, or both?

Answer (score 5):

You are effectively asking the question `"My company wants email. How do I set up email for my company?"` - If you need to ask this question my answer is "You go to http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html and pay Google to help you do it right."  If you don't want to use Google there are other options (like [Hosted Exchange](http://www.godaddy.com/email/hosted-exchange.aspx) which is available from a bunch of providers - all of whom will help you get things set up & working).

Email is a specialist task - It doesn't sound like you have the necessary experience to do it in-house. If something goes wrong and your company can't send/receive mail it will be nothing but Bad Times for you.

Comment: Exactly right. He's going to either pay for Google or Hosted Exchange, or pay qualified staff (which will cost more), or mess it up because he has unqualified staff and is depending on ServerFault to be his architects and tech support.

Comment: @mfinni we're great architects, but when it comes to support we usually just like to point and laugh at the misfortune of others :)

Comment: Sure, we're great architects. We don't usually do this much work for free though :-)